# Keeping the old value when a division by zero occurs

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector D of length N and a matrix A of shape N*M. Vector D has some zero elements. I'm doing this operation:

```
D = D.reshape(-1,1)
A / D
```

Since D has some zeros then I will get a division by zero error. What I want is not to modify the value of A where the division by zero occurs. So if A[i,j] / 0, then I want A[i,j] to keep its value. How to do this?

Comment: You might want to make sure you are clear on the [difference between numpy arrays and matrices](http://wiki.scipy.org/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users#head-e9a492daa18afcd86e84e07cd2824a9b1b651935)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
A = np.where(D != 0, A / D, A)
```